# Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout - Android issue

Tags: java, android, xml, gradle, tabs

I am trying to run my app but the following error still occures

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.phonebookapp, PID: 23308
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.phonebookapp/com.example.phonebookapp.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2763)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2824)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #23: Error inflating class com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
     Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426)
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
        at com.example.phonebookapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6775)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2716)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2824)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
     Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Can't convert value at index 10 to dimension: type=0x1c
        at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDimensionPixelSize(TypedArray.java:720)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:426)
        at com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout.<init>(TabLayout.java:399)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:430) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:645) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:787) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:727) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:858) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:861) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:821) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:518) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:426) 
        at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:377) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555) 
        at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161) 
        at com.example.phonebookapp.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:20) 
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6775) 
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1119) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2716) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2824) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1546) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786) 
Disconnected from the target VM, address: 'localhost:8600', transport: 'socket'
```

That is my xml file for MainActivity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/myToolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light">
        </androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar>

        <com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/myTablayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="@android:color/white"
            app:tabMode="fixed" >
        </com.google.android.material.tabs.TabLayout>

    </com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>

    <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/myViewPager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager>
```

In Gradle file I have implemented proper library: implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'

Please help me with this. because this is my entry to android and I do not understand these errors yet.

Answer (score 3):

You have a color entered where it is looking for a number (height),
Line 22 I think

```
app:tabIndicatorHeight="@android:color/white"
```

Change this to a number an see if it works